how to change rank of a VB.NET String-Array variable
I need to port VBA-code to VB.NET.
VBA has variable type "Variant", which you can feed anything.
Our VBA-Project has a lot of lines likes (very simplyfied):
Dim v as Variant

v = GetRecords(strSQL)
If RankExists(v, 2) Then
   bla = v(i, j)
   call MyFunctionX(v)
Else
   bla = v(i)
   call MyFunctionX(v)
End If

There is a GetRecords() method which returns either an Array of rank 1 or 2. Without going to deep into the detail: GetRecords() is retreiving data from table and returns either am Array of rank 2 with rows and columns (SELECT * FROM Table1) of the table or it returns an array of rank 1 with only the values of a single column or a single row (SELECT A, B FROM Table1 WHERE UNIQUE_ID=1).
RankExists() is a simple functions which determines if an array is 1D or 2D.
I don't know what's the best way to solve my issue, that I cannot declare my Variable v as Variant anymore.
The code continues with the use of v - so I cannot declare 2 variables, one for 1D and another for 2D arrays.
I am really stuck at the moment, how to convert that simple piece of code neatly from VBA to .NET

What determines what the strSQL query is? It might be better to start from that consideration.

There's a reason .NET is doing things differently - you now have a vast number of tools at your disposal to improve your code. Look into an ORM such as EF. It will be many changes but you will benefit greatly. If you don't want to change, see my answer

That GetRecords() function looks incredibly dangerous, like it's forcing you to build SQL in the app in a way that will be crazy-vulnerable to sql injection.

@AndrewMorton and Joel : I knew it, I should't have mentioned anything about SQL. It's not about SQL - it's about having a variable which may hold a 1D or 2D array at runtime. Some examples: user wants to generate random numbers - e.g. only a few -> 1D user wants to generate a block of random numbers for a 6x7 matrice e.g. powerball. It's not that specific case above - it's a general coding pattern I encouter, that a variable is Variant and holds on runtime a 1D or 2D array. But maybe best not to port code 1:1 but to adjust the logic behind it to VB.NET constrains.

A simple way to solve that would be to always use a 2D array, that only has a single column when you want a 1D one, so that the runtime type is the same, so you can avoid Variant and all the problems it creates.

Ok encapsulate in a class holding some quantity of vectors. Variant was used in VB6 because Microsoft used it. Scripting.Dictionary always held a variant, it's true. But it doesn't mean it should be overused, even in VB6.

An IEnumerable(Of Integer()) is an example of something you could use in .NET. One method could handle this, and iterate over the outer list, only a single iteration for a "one dimensional array". There are many ways to solve your problem while using strongly-typed variables.

Overloading and logic adjustment is probably the way to go: varMonths = Array(jan, feb, march, ...) then we have this useful function varMonths = buildArray(arrIn As Variant, rowCount, colCount) which transforms the given input array into a new array with given dimensions and we use the same variable for the result: varMonths = buildArray(varMonths, 4, 3) what should use a new result variable: monthTable = buildArray(varMonthNames, 4, 3) and use overloading for buildArray(String()) and buildArray(String(,)) or even buildArray(int()) and long(), ....

@SUSiS Don't ever use Variant in .Net code.

You now have Object in VB.Net which is very similar to VB6 Variant. Whenever possible, avoid declaring anything as Object, however there are cases where it is necessary so it's not something to avoid blindly.
Your method signatures can change to use object
Private Function GetRecords(query As String) As Object

End Function

Private Sub MyFunction(records As Object)

End Sub

Your RankExists can be changed to this, assuming your query returns an array of strings
Private Function RankExists(records As Object, index As Integer) As Boolean
    Select Case index
        Case 1
            Return records.GetType() Is GetType(String())
        Case 2
            Return records.GetType() Is GetType(String(,))
    End Select
    Return False
End Function

Your example code can be
Dim v As Object

v = GetRecords(strSQL)
If RankExists(v, 2) Then
    Dim bla = CType(v, String(,))(i, j)
    MyOtherFunctionTakingArray(bla)
    ' or pass an object to the function
    MyFunctionX(v)
Else
    Dim bla = CType(v, String())(i)
    MyOtherFunctionTakingString(bla)
    MyFunctionX(v)
End If

The downside is you are holding everything in Objects, and you will be boxing / unboxing all the time. If you aren't familiar with this concept, familiarize yourself with it, and you will most likely decide not to do this.
Really, don't do this, and redesign your database stuff. You will not regret doing that. Moving from VB6 to .NET is ideally not trivial, else you will end up with really poor code.

In this case, you could use the Array type rather than Object, so at least you're being specific to arrays and would get some members to help with array operations.

The move to .Net is a move to a fundamentally strongly-typed platform with real object-oriented support instead of the pseudo-object-oriented support from the VB6 era. That means functions and variables in .Net always have specific return types. Even if you don't declare a type, you get Object. This is similar to Variant, but not quite as flexible.
With that in mind, you'll want to declare two methods for .Net, and use the appropriate method in the appropriate places. This is why, for example, the ADO.Net (which you should also start using at this point) has multiple methods for ExecuteSclar(), ExecuteNonQuery(), ExecuteReader(), and Fill().
Additionally, methods like GetRecords() are fundamentally unsafe if they only have an argument for the SQL statement without also expecting parameter data. It's hard to overstate how bad this is! This was bad in the old classic ADO/VB6 -era, too!
In short, you should expect to re-architect some things for this migration.
